# I'm trying a program of setZeroes() in an mXn matrix by using vector and I get the following error-

Tags: arrays, matrix, stdvector

Line 1037: Char 9: runtime error: reference binding to null pointer of type 'std::vector<int, std::allocator>' (stl_vector.h)
SUMMARY: UndefinedBehaviorSanitizer: undefined-behavior /usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/11/../../../../include/c++/11/bits/stl_vector.h:1046:9

I'm trying to set all the elements of ith row and jth column as 0 when flag[i][j] value is 0. My code is as follows-

```
void setZeroes(vector<vector<int>>& matrix) {
    int m= matrix.size();
    int n= matrix[0].size();

    vector<vector<int>> flag;
    for(int i=0; i<m;i++) 
    { 
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++) 
        { 
            if(matrix[i][j]==0){
                flag[i][j]=0;
            }
            else{
                flag[i][j]=1;
            }
        }     
    }

    for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
        for(int j=0;j<n;j++){
            if(flag[i][j]==0){
                int trow=0, tcol=0;
                while(trow<m){
                    matrix[trow++][j]=0;
                }
                while(tcol<n){
                    matrix[i][tcol++]=0;
                }
            }
        }  
    }
}
```

Here is the question link- https://leetcode.com/problems/set-matrix-zeroes/

I tried defining the size of flag but it resulted in error. I'm not very familiar with vectors so can't really determine what's wrong.

Thanks for any kind of help!